# mahapps metro tabcontrol as prism region style

Tags: wpf, prism, region, tabitem, mahapps.metro

I have problem with prism and mahapps.metro library. I set TabControl as my region in my Shell and here i have problem beacouse every tabitem(module) not react on Triggers for example: Property="IsMouseOver". Headers have the same style and i dont know how to force them to work properly. Here is my code:

Shell.xaml

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}" TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="HeaderStyle">
        <Setter Property="Header"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Path=Content.DataContext.TabModel.Title}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl Grid.Row="1" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.TabContainer}" Style="{StaticResource MetroTabControl}"/>
```

And module:

```
<TabItem x:Class="DataConverter.Modules.Export.Views.MenuView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}"
         Header="Export"
         IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsSelected}">
```

when i remove `Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}"` my tabitem looks like standard control. How to resolve this?

Comment: I'm confused! You have a style static resource with a key that you want to have applied implicitly?